# Ionic 3: How to delete an image from the PhotoLibrary?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

In an Ionic 3 app I have a photo gallery which displays images from an album. It works fine, but I can't delete an image.

A `LibraryItem`, as retrieved by `cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.getLibrary` looks like this:

```
creationDate: Sat Nov 04 2017 21:21:33 GMT-0400 (EDT)
fileName: "2017-10-5-1.jpg"
height: 960
id: "1937;/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Timelapser/2017-10-5-1.jpg"
latitude: 0
longitude: 0
photoURL: "cdvphotolibrary://photo?photoId=1937%3B%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FPictures%2FTimelapser%2F2017-10-5-1.jpg"
thumbnailURL: "cdvphotolibrary://thumbnail?photoId=1937%3B%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FPictures%2FTimelapser%2F2017-10-5-1.jpg&width=512&height=384&quality=0.8"
width: 1280
```

I am trying to delete this (or any other) image file. However anything I try, Cordova throws an error and the file doesn't seem to exist. Ionic's manual is quite hazy at this point. This is all it says:

```
removeFile(path, fileName)
```

The parameters are pretty obvious, except what are they supposed to be? I tried everything, extracted path and filename from the `photoURL` value, but nothing seems to help. Neither `checkFile` nor `removeFile` seems to find the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not delete a file from the cdvphotolibrary:// url. If you want to delete a file,  you need to have file:/// native url.

check the [Getting native file location](https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library/issues/60) open issue with the PhotoLibary plugin.

[AndreasGassmann](https://github.com/AndreasGassmann) has a [fork](https://github.com/AndreasGassmann/cordova-plugin-photo-library/tree/nativeFileUrls) that returns the native url also. As per him you can get the native urls:

- getNativeThumbnailUrl
- getNativePhotoUrl

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I figured it out and got to the conclusion that PhotoLibrary is a very half-baked component. I am using File now.